# Regular expression extract string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `"@{Name; 11112121@xyz.com}"`

I want to write a regular expression that extracts `Name` and `11112121` from the above string

This is what I tried.

```
function formatName(text){ 
  var regex = /@\{([^;]+); ([^\}]+)\}/
  return text.replace(
      regex,
      '$1, $2'
  );  
}
```

The above gives `Name, 11112121@xyz.com`. But I want only `Name, 11112121`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
var regex = /@\{([^;]+); ([^\}]+)(@.*)\}/
```

$1 => Name

$2=> 11112121

[Here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/39L) is the working example

Answer (score 2):

Use match instead, like this:

```
var regex = /@\{([^;]+);\s+([^@]+)/;

var matches = text.match(regex);

alert(matches[1] + ', ' + matches[2]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/bM2U6/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match everything until the `@` character, you can use

```
var regex = /@\{([^;]+); ([^@]+)/
```

If you need to verify that the string also contains a `}` after that, you can add that to the end:

```
var regex = /@\{([^;]+); ([^@]+)[^}]*\}/
```